# Step Backward shortcut doesn't work after upgrading to Photoshop CC 2018

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have upgraded my Photoshop CC 2017 to the 2018 version. Since, pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> doesn't do anything. It works only when manually clicking ***Edit » Step Backward***. How to fix it?

Comment: In the History Panel flyout menu.. is the shortcut still shown to the right of the Step Backwards menu item?

Comment: @Scott In the Edit menu yes. I didn't understand what you said about the History Panel.

Comment: If the shortcut is still listed in the menu but does not work, then you have other technical issues, which can't really be solved here. You should ask Adobe.

Comment: @Sipo The right answer for this question is that **it's a known bug**. Just first press CTRL and then ALT + Z as a temporary fix, Adobe is already working on a [fix](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2397608)